# How to seperate incorrect and correct answers if option type is 'Yes or No' or 'True or False'

Tags: php

In piece of code below, it display a list of letters from A-Z depending on `$OptionType` (e.g. OptionType  is A-D, then it displays letters A B C D). Then it removes the correct answer (`$dbAnswer`) so it is left with displaying the incorrect answers.

E.g Correct Answer is `B`. So Incorrect Answer it shows is A C D.

Now this works fine for letters.

The problem I have is that it does not remove correct answers from incorrect answers if option is `True or False` or `Yes or No`? For example if option type is `True or False`, if `True` is correct and `False` is incorrect, then it should only display `False` answer, but instead it displays both answers `True` and `False`. How can I only split incorrect and correct answers if option type is `True or False` or `Yes or No`.

Below is code:

```
   while ($stmt->fetch()) {

// Do this for each row:
if ( array_key_exists( $dbOptionType, $specialOptionTypes ) ) {
    $options = $specialOptionTypes[$dbOptionType];
} else if ( preg_match( '/^([A-Z])-([A-Z])$/', $dbOptionType, $match ) ) {
    $options = range( $match[1], $match[2] );
} else {
    // issue warning about unrecognized option type
    $options = array();
}
$right = str_split( $dbAnswer ); 
$wrong = array_diff( $options, $right );  

        $incorrect_ans[] = $wrong;

      }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$specialOptionTypes = array('Yes or No' => array( 'Yes', 'No' ),'True or False' => array( 'True', 'False' ));

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

// Do this for each row:
if ( array_key_exists( $dbOptionType, $specialOptionTypes ) ) {
    $options = $specialOptionTypes[$dbOptionType];
} else if ( preg_match( '/^([A-Z])-([A-Z])$/', $dbOptionType, $match ) ) {
    $options = range( $match[1], $match[2] );
} else {
    // issue warning about unrecognized option type
    $options = array();
}
$right = $dbAnswer; // $right = 'True';

foreach ($options as $option) {
   // To echo out 'wrong' answers
   if ($option !== $right) {
      echo $option . '<br>';
   } 
}
$wrong = array_diff( $options, $right );  


        $incorrect_ans[] = $wrong;

      }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're saving either 'True' or 'False' as strings in your DB, make sure you're doing the right comparison in PHP. True/False, by its nature, is a different data type (a boolean rather than a string):

```
$right = $dbAnswer; // $right = 'True';

foreach ($options as $option) {
   // To echo out 'wrong' answers
   if ($option !== $right) {
      echo $option . '<br>';
   } 
}
```

The difference between `==` and `===` is that the latter compares not only value, but data type.

---

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
   // To echo out 'wrong' answers
   if ($option !== $right) {
      $incorrectAnswersArray[] = $option;
   } 
}

// You now have all the incorrect answers in $incorrectAnswersArray
$firstIncorrectAnswer = $incorrectAnswersArray[0];
$secondIncorrectAnswer = $incorrectAnswersArray[1];
// etc.
```

Comment: I think he wants to echo the incorrect answers so `($option !== $right)`....I think, kind of hard to understand question. +1

Comment: Can I ask how to implement your code into my code because as you can see I have three different option types `True or False`, `Yes or No`, or letter options which is any option type such as `A-C`, `A-D`, `A-E` etc. Yes i want to echo the incorrect answers

Comment: Use the above code and let me know how you get on. What should happen is that it will retrieve the correct answer from the DB (e.g. 'False'), and it does a strict comparison against every option. If the option fails the comparison (i.e. it's incorrect), it will echo out.

Comment: Seems to me he is going through a lot to do this. Can you show us more of the actual query. I think you could just use `str_replace` and simplify this greatly.

Comment: `str_replace` might not work because there are multiple options. You need to compare a string against an array of strings. You could use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) but I wanted to aim for clarity rather than minimal code.

Comment: Depending on his query, may be able to get away form all of the arrays and just loop the resulting rows with `wrong = str_replace($dbAnswer, "", "$row['avaliable_answers']");`

Comment: Sorry my mistake, my incorrect answers go in an array , dont need to echo it, it is working for letter options, just not for `True or False` or `Yes or No` options. I don't understand your answer because I already have the code which successfully splits the correct answers and the incorrect answers, but it is only doing it for the letter options. not for the `True or False` or `Yes or No` options

Comment: You are not successfully sorting 'True', 'False', 'Yes', and 'No' answers from the options. You are trying to use `str_split` which explodes a string of letters (i.e. ABCD) into an array (A, B, C, D) and then finding the difference. This **will not work** for the other answer types. You need to retrieve all the options and loop through the array, comparing each option against the correct `$dbAnswer`. Only then will you differentiate between them. What happens when you try my code?

Comment: I ma getting this error: Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array. I think I put code in wrong place. I include update in question

Comment: @user1930247 I've updated my answer - you can replace the last bit of your code with mine and it should work. Look at my comments to understand what it does

Comment: @Jamie I understand what it does but I am getting errors. It is because the way I am echoing the answers. I am getting errors in array_interset(). I upvoted answer. I have been trying to echo it but failing badly. So I have pasted you code into mine, I have put the array intersect back to what it was. I am successfully ehoing incorrect answers if answers are letter types, now how do you echo incorrect answers from true, false, and echo incorrect answers from yes, no? Last question. Do this and it should work and then I can mark your answer

Comment: @user1930247 Do not use array_intersect(). All of the incorrect answers - no matter what the type - is contained in `$incorrectAnswersArray`. You therefore do not need to do apply any comparison functions to this array - just echo out the incorrect answers which is what I thought you wanted.

Comment: PHP FIDDLE showing code here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ncu-27m, use this so you can see what I am doing. The fact is that I am not sure with your code how much drastic changes we are making so just hav a look.

Comment: Link to PHP fiddle doesn't seem to work - website might be down. Pastebin?

Comment: Why are you doing `$wrong = array_diff( $options, $right );`? **You do not need to do this**. You _already_ have differentiated the correct options from the incorrect ones. All the incorrect ones are stored in `$incorrectAnswersArray` and the correct answer is `$dbAnswer`. You do not need to do any more array functions.

Comment: @Jamie Yeah I know what you mean, but what I am asking you is remove the parts I do not need. I had the `array_diff(... ` because that was my old code when separating correct and incorrect answers which only worked for letter answers. I'm asking remove the parts I do not need from my code so then I can test your theory on the browser. It will be easier for me as you have knowledge on your theory

Comment: I'm not writing your script for you. I've provided the answer - you need to actually read my answer and understand the (very basic) ideas behind it

Comment: Im sorry , I can't understand it, if I remove the `$wrong = array_diff( $options, $right );` then I am not going to seperate the correct and incorrect answers for letter buttons. That is what I am trying to say to you, the code I have works for letter answers, I just need it to work for true or false and yes or no as well. Not replace what I have.

Comment: Figured it out all I needed was my old code and change `$right = str_split( $dbAnswer );` to `$right = array( $dbAnswer ); ` That was all that was needed to be done

Comment: @user1930247 that's awesome, well done. Do you need any more help with something else? If not, you might want to consider marking an answer as accepted :)